# Filter List based of optional List

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

I have an optional list of Integers, 
`Optional<List<Integer>> id.`

I have a list of many different people. `List<People> people.`

I have a filter method that takes takes the optional filter. The code calls the repository to get a list of people and, if the Optional list of id's is populated, will filter the people within the list against the id's. People.getId().

I want to use the steams API to avoid editing the original list. I have tried something like this

```
 return people.stream()
            .filter(p -> !request.getId().orElseGet(ArrayList::new).contains(p.getId()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The spec is.

- if no id's, return all
- if id's provided - filter
- if id's provided and no matches, return empty list

The above fails when the no id's match, it returns a full list.

```
Optional<List<Integer>> ids = Optional.of(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
List<People> people = datasource...

List<People> filter (Optional < List < Integer >>> ids) {
    List<People> confusion = people.steam(). ?
    return confusion;
}
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You don't need Java8 and Optionals here. Just use a for loop and do it. Java8 is NOT the silver bullet that solves all your problems.

Comment: `Optional` is not generally recommended for parameters. It will give you a clearer interface if the caller only calls `filter` when they actually want filtering done. The caller could do something like `filteredList = ids.map(this::filter).orElse(people);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if no id's, return all

Firstly, You just need an `||` condition. If the the `Optional` is empty then the `Optional.isPresent()` would be `false`, so adding a `!ids.isPresent()` before the `||` will return you all the items from the `filter` as the `||` is a short-circuit operation as the condition on the left of the `||` is `true` the entire condition will be `true`.

> if id's provided - filter

Secondly, the `!` needs to be removed from your check and you need this check on the right of the `||`: `ids.get().contains(p.getId())` to filter using the list of ids from the `Optional`.

> if id's provided and no matches, return empty list

Thirdly, if `ids` is present then the second check will be evaluated as the first check `!ids.isPresent()` becomes `false`. The `People` object will be checked if the `id` matches with the list from the `Optional` if nothing matches an empty list is returned.

So all three can be applied below:

```
List<People> list = people.stream()
                        .filter(p -> !ids.isPresent() || ( ids.get().isEmpty() || ids.get().contains(p.getId())))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Also, it would be better if you would use an `Optional<Set<Integer>>` instead of a `Optional<List<Integer>>`, then `contains()` would be constant time operation.

Answer (score 1):

That's all.

```
List<People> filter (Optional < List < Integer >>> idsOpt) {
    return 
        idsOpt.map(
            ids ->
                people.stream()
                    .filter(p -> ids.contains(p.getId())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        ).orElse(people);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> First, we eliminate case when the user gave us no input.

```
if (ids == null || !ids.isPresent() || ids.get().isEmpty())
    return getPeopleFromSomewhere();
```

> Second, we handle a scenario where a user actually gave us something

```
people.stream()
        .filter(p -> ids.get().stream().anyMatch(id -> id.equals(p.getId())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

> Eventually, if the user gave us the ids, that do not match, we will return the filtered empty list.

The final version will look like something along these lines.

```
public List doSomething() {
    Optional<List<Integer>> ids = Optional.of(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
    List<People> people = getPeopleFromSomewhere();

    if (ids == null || !ids.isPresent() || ids.get().isEmpty())
        return people;

    return people.stream()
            .filter(p -> ids.get().stream().anyMatch(id -> id.equals(p.getId())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to solve that effectively would be

```
List<People> filteringOperation(Optional<List<Integer>> id, List<People> people) {
    Set<Integer> uniqueIds = id.isPresent() ? new HashSet<>(id.get()) : Collections.emptySet();
    return uniqueIds.isEmpty() ? people : people.stream()
            .filter(p -> uniqueIds.contains(p.getId()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The above follows the specs such as:

- if no id's, return all

If the `id` list is empty the `uniqueIds` would be empty and the existing list of all `people` would be returned.

- if id's provided - filter

If the `id` list has values those values would be collected into a `Set` and people with id contained in that set would be filtered in the resulting list.

- if id's provided and no matches, return empty list

The stream implementation also implies that if ids provided do not match any person in the people list, an empty list would be returned.